# WordPress Child Themes include_once

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm trying to create a child theme to override some functions in my parent theme

i have this in parent functions.php theme

```
 include_once('admin/functions-extended/fn-typography.php'); //User Typography
```

This is my try:

```
  include_once(get_stylesheet_directory().'admin/functions-extended/fn-typography.php' );
```

## but not work

more details

i'm trying add custom fonts in this file but in child theme 
the code in parent fn-typography.php is

```
function mgm_get_google_fonts() {
// Google Font Defaults
$google_faces = array(
    "Abel" => "Abel",
    "Abril Fatface" => "Abril Fatface",
    "Aclonica" => "Aclonica",
    "Acme" => "Acme",
    "Actor" => "Actor",
    "Adamina" => "Adamina",
    "Advent Pro" => "Advent Pro",
    "Aguafina Script" => "Aguafina Script",
    "Aladin" => "Aladin",
    "Aldrich" => "Aldrich",
    "Alegreya" => "Alegreya",
    "Alegreya SC" => "Alegreya SC",
    "Alex Brush" => "Alex Brush",
    "Alfa Slab One" => "Alfa Slab One",
    "Alice" => "Alice",
    "Alike" => "Alike",
    "Alike Angular" => "Alike Angular",
    "Allan" => "Allan",
            );
return $google_faces;
   }
```

i want remove this fonts and add another fonts

Comment: Are you trying to use fn-typography.php or override it?

Comment: @bobdye im trying override it

Comment: Do you have a file of the same name in the exact same directory structure in your child theme? Also, does the parent function.php allow it? If you simply include a function again, you'll get a "Duplicate function name" error.

Comment: @bobdye so how can add some custom fonts load only in child theme in   function mgm_get_google_fonts() {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you show, mgm_get_google_fonts() is not actually loading fonts, but apparently providing a list of fonts for some other function to load.

The comment in the parent function describes it as providing defaults, so implies that there is some way to override them. From looking through the parent functions.php, you can probably figure out how you can do that.

For example, if the parent theme allows you to override this function, it will probably say something like:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'mgm_get_google_fonts') {
    ...the function definition you have above...
}
```

This tests to see if you have defined a function of the same name in your child theme and uses yours if you have.

If the parent theme doesn't do this, they you will need to look where mgm_get_google_fonts is called and track down how to override.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever happens in your parent functions.php will also be done by your child theme, so you don't have to include that file separately because it will be included when activating your child theme.

If you want to change behaviour in a file included by your theme which you can't override trough get_template_part (like library PHP files), than you should look for a technique that the theme builder has implemented for you, if any. Mostly by an hook.